# jQuery checkbox check uncheck child checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have a parent child category checkbox, to which child has sub-child. Child category only needs to gets displayed when parent category is clicked and when parent category is unchecked all child category needs to get hidden.

Every thing works fine but when, suppose the child and subchild are checked. now when super-parent is unchecked then it hides the checkbox keeping subchild selected that should get unchecked.

here is my code.

```
$(function () {
$(':checkbox').change(function () {
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
    var inner_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (inner_id.search("parent") > -1) {
    //   $("input."+inner_id).attr('hidden','false')
    $("."+inner_id).removeAttr("hidden");
    }
});
});
});

$(function () {
    $(':checkbox').click(function () {
    var is_chk = $(this).attr('checked');
    var its_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (is_chk != 'checked') {
        $("."+its_id).attr('hidden', 'true');
    }
});
});
```

the html code for this is.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="parent1" />parent<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="parent1" disabled="true" />child1<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="parent1" disabled="true"/>child2<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="parent1" disabled="true"/>child3<br/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="parent2" />parent<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"  class="parent2" disabled="true"/>child1<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" class="parent2" 
 id="parent3" disabled="true"/>child2-parent<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"
 class="parent3" disabled="true"/>child1<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"
 class="parent3"  disabled="true"/>child2<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"
 class="parent3"  disabled="true"/>child3<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox"
 class="parent3"  disabled="true"/>child4<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" 
 class="parent3" id="parent4"  disabled="true"/>child5-parent<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" 
 class="parent4"  disabled="true"/>child1<br/>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" 
 class="parent4"  disabled="true"/>child2<br/>
```

or you can try it out here.

http://jsfiddle.net/DNDnT/4/

just check-all check-box and click parent you will understand my problem.
Thanks.

The Actual code that i have tried in my project is.

```
$(function() {
$(':checkbox').change(function() {

$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() { 
  //var inner_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var inner_id = $(this).attr('value');
  var parId1="input."+inner_id;
  var parId2="."+inner_id;

$(parId1).removeAttr("disabled");
  $(parId2).removeAttr("hidden");

});
});
}); 

$(function() {
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
var is_chk = $(this).attr('checked');
   var its_id = $(this).attr('value'); 
   //var parId2="#"+its_id;
    var parId1="input."+its_id;
    var parId2="."+its_id;


    if(is_chk!='checked') {
        $(parId1).removeAttr("checked");
        $(parId1).attr('disabled','true');
        $(parId2).attr('hidden','true');

    }
});
});
```

Comment: do not have time to play with your fiddle, but maybe try something like this `$("."+its_id).attr('checked', false);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you have written works, just saw your fiddle. But If that's what you want, then you can try adding this line in a second function :

```
$("."+its_id).attr('checked', false);
```

before

```
$("."+its_id).attr('hidden', 'true');
```

Comment: It only removes the checked value of current class, what about child of child thats my actual problem.